# ask iphone device orientation to refresh

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, orientation

I'm creating a puzzle game for the iphone. All of my menus, etc are only in the portrait orientation, but my gameplay can be in either portrait or landscape.

So when I'm in the menu and the device is being held in landscape, then when I go to the gameplay viewcontroller, it does the layout with the landscape coordinates, but the screen is still actually oriented portrait-wise:

[image]

**I want to force the device to re-orient the screen before I do the layout.** How do I do that?

right now I'm testing for device orientation like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    .
    .
    .

   if (!UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
      // Run Portrait Layout
   }
   else {
      // Run Landscape Layout
   }
}
```

So I know that the device is returning an orientation of landscape, but the screen is still oriented portrait for some reason.

Comment: Have you enabled the supported orientation in project settings? Maybe you're portrait-locked?

Comment: Thanks but No its not that. Once I'm in the GamePlay the rotations work fine. Its only if I load the VC while the Device is in landscape

Comment: @aking63 Let me rephrase your question. Its like, if you open your game in Landscape mode and then change its orientation, then your view does not refresh. Right? So you want to refresh you view every time on change of orientation?

Comment: @sanchitsingh no its only the initial setup. As soon as I change the phone's orientation, it figures out what it should be doing. But even if its held in landscape during the pushViewController event, it loads with the screen facing portrait.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps try..

```
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

In `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, that should make it attempt an orientation change

Comment: This magic method is still working like a charm in Swift 4.2!: UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods in UIViewController that you can override to catch the view-did-rotate event:

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

Do check the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: this isnt what I need. It responds to orientation changes, but doesn't always initially get it right. Thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: OK. As what I understand now, you shouldn't use [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation], but self.interfaceOrientation